# Wordpress pagination not visible from loop

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm doing a blog with Wordpress and the post pagination doesn't appear. The post list is shown correctly, but there is only 5 post (I have 8) and pagination isn't working.

```
<?php
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="all-post">
        <?php
        $args = array('category' => '');
        $myposts = get_posts($args);
        foreach ($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <div class="post">
                <div class="post-thumbnail">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="post-details">
                    <div class="post-meta">
                        <span class="date"><?php the_time('j M, Y'); ?></span>
                        <!--  Categories  -->
                        <span class="categories">
                            <?php
                            $category_ids = get_all_category_ids();
                            ?><?php
                            $args = array('orderby' => 'slug', 'parent' => 0);
                            $categories = get_categories($args);
                            foreach ($categories as $category)
                            {
                                echo '<a href="' . get_category_link(
                                        $category->term_id
                                    ) . '" rel="bookmark" class="category">' . $category->name . '' . $category->description . '</a>';
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older posts'); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link('Newer posts'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe didn't set any `posts_per_page` value and the default is 5. If you want to modifiy it for the whole website blog/archive pages, modify the posts_per_page value in the Reading Settings page.

In a `$args` array, modify as folow:

```
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page'=> -1, // unlimited
   'category' => ''
);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

I'm prudent with my answer (that why I give 2 methods to achieve this), because I don't know with your given code, if the main loop $args is modify.

I hope this could nevertheless help you.